# Extracting words from array

Tags: java

I have this strings:
 " one, two, three, 4,"
What I want to do is to get "one", "two", "three" in an array space so when I print the array I get "one" "two" "three". I have this code but all I get is "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"

```
 for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))&&s.charAt(i)!=',')
        words[j]=""+s.charAt(i);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for downvoting my question but not telling me why is not even giving me "onetwothree" instead of "eeeeeeeeeeeee"

Comment: @up: 'cause your logic is wrong.

Comment: that is the string exactly  " one, ,two three,4," not "one,two,three,4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then try this

```
   String test = " one, ,two three,4,";
    //replace all digit to blank
    test = test.replaceAll("\\d+", "");
    List<String> splittedText = Splitter.on(",").omitEmptyStrings().trimResults().splitToList(test);
    String combineWords = "";
    for (String word : splittedText) {
        combineWords+=word+" ";
    }

    List<String> finalSplittedWord = Splitter.on(" ").omitEmptyStrings().splitToList(combineWords);
    for (String word : finalSplittedWord) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```

Output

```
  one
  two
  three
```

[Splitter.on](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is from Google Guava library .Download the jar & use it on your project

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt. This method works with every language and every space character:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Split {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = " one, two, three, 4,";
        System.out.println(getWords(str));
    }

    public static List<String> getWords(String str) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str
            .split("[,\\s+]")));
        list.removeIf(s -> s.isEmpty()
            || !s.chars().allMatch(c -> Character.isAlphabetic(c)));
        return list;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[one, two, three]
```

However it only works in Java 8. If you need it to work in Java 7 it's a bit longer:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Split {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = " one, two, three, 4,";
        System.out.println(getWords(str));
    }

    public static List<String> getWords(String str) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split("[,\\s+]")));

        Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String part = it.next();
            if (part.isEmpty()) {
                it.remove();
                continue;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < part.length(); i++) {
                if (!Character.isAlphabetic(part.charAt(i))) {
                    it.remove();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[one, two, three]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
String[] words = s.split(",");
```

Edit:
If your string is exacltly like " one, two, three, 4,", it looks like you are searching for whole words. This should help:

```
String s = " one, ,two three,4,";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    stringList.add(m.group(1));
}
String[] words = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
```